# TypeError: expected CPU (got CUDA)

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
torch.cuda.current_device()
torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
torch.cuda.memory_reserved()
torch.cuda.memory_allocated()
torch.cuda.memory_allocated()
var1=torch.FloatTensor([1.0,2.0,3.0]).cuda()
var1
var1.device
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')
df.head()
df.isnull().sum()

import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
df['Outcome']=np.where(df['Outcome']==1,"Diabetic","No Diabetic")
df.head()
sns.pairplot(df,hue="Outcome")
X=df.drop('Outcome',axis=1).values### independent features
y=df['Outcome'].values###dependent features
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
y_train
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

```
X_train=torch.FloatTensor(X_train).cuda()
X_test=torch.FloatTensor(X_test).cuda()
y_train=torch.LongTensor(y_train).cuda()
y_test=torch.LongTensor(y_test).cuda()
```

when I Run this code I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 24, in <module>
TypeError: expected CPU (got CUDA)
```

How to can I solve this error?

Comment: ##### Creating Tensors
X_train=torch.FloatTensor(X_train).cuda()
X_test=torch.FloatTensor(X_test).cuda()
y_train=torch.LongTensor(y_train).cuda()
y_test=torch.LongTensor(y_test).cuda()

Comment: Please read how to [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65679823/edit) button to improve your post.

Comment: and the error is: >>> X_train=torch.FloatTensor(X_train).cuda()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected CPU (got CUDA)

Comment: @VinothKumarS, does your m/c have a GPU? Are you performing any operation with mixed CPU/GPU types? Is the pytorch GPU version? Show the complete error msg!

Comment: @anurag yes my machine has GPU that is RTX 3070 and it is the PyTorch GPU version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To transfer the variables to GPU, try the following:

```py
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

X_train=torch.FloatTensor(X_train).to(device)
X_test=torch.FloatTensor(X_test).to(device)
y_train=torch.LongTensor(y_train).to(device)
y_test=torch.LongTensor(y_test).to(device)
```

Comment: `cuda:0` - here change `0` to the desired index of GPU (if you have multiple GPUs)

Comment: Thank you so much sir! It's working now and can you explain a little bit why we need to use this?

Comment: I am not sure why your code did not work, however, as per the discussion [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-doing-net-cuda-vs-net-to-device/69278/3) there shouldn't be any difference! Also, kindly upvote/accept if this solved your problem!